# How to add second part to a discord command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

I am trying to create a command for my discord.py bot. It is: ".see". The user who executes the command must specify the user that he'd like to see, by adding the user's name after the command. Ex: .see [user] | .see HelloWorld

My question is... how can I do this? How can I add this second part to the command?
This is all I have at the moment:

```
@bot.command()
async def see(ctx):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by adding arguments to the python function. And there is even a way to automatically make the argument by a `discord.Member` so the command could be executed with `.see @Member`, `.see member_id`, `.see MemberName#Discriminator` and so on:

```py
@bot.command()
async def see(ctx, person:discord.Member):
    ctx.send(person.display_name) # Person is now the member object the command has to be executed with
```